# How Filter data When key attribute is in child Table +spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

There are 2 table, Parent is MeetingTypes Child is Meetings they have1 : m mapping
Meeting has releaseID atribute so i want to filter its by releaseID .but problem is, its in Child Table...
If it is Parent Table we can do it simply and it is working

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from MeetingTypes where releaseID= :releaseID");
    query.setParameter("releaseID", releaseID);
    List list = query.list();       
     if(list!=null && list.size()>0){
        return  list;
    }else{
    return null;
    }
```

I tried it this way

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
                  "from MeetingTypes mt join mt.Meetings m " +
                          "where m.releaseID = :releaseID");

        query.setParameter("releaseID", releaseID);

        return query.list();
```

But give bellow Erro

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from MeetingTypes mt join mt.Meetings m where m.releaseID = 192' at 
line 1
```

relevant tabales

```
package pearson.dashboard.model;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;



@Entity
public class MeetingTypes {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int meetingTypeID;
    @Column
    private String typeName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingTypes",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    private List<Meetings> meetings;
    public List<Meetings> getMeetings() {
        return meetings;
    }

    public void setMeetings(List<Meetings> meetings) {
        this.meetings = meetings;
    }

    public MeetingTypes() {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MeetingTypes(int meetingTypeID, String typeName
            ) {
        super();
        this.meetingTypeID = meetingTypeID;
        this.typeName = typeName;

    }

    public int getMeetingTypeID() {
        return meetingTypeID;
    }

    public void setMeetingTypeID(int meetingTypeID) {
        this.meetingTypeID = meetingTypeID;
    }

    public String getTypeName() {
        return typeName;
    }

    public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }



}
```

---

```
package pearson.dashboard.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;

@Entity
public class Meetings {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int meetingID;
    @Column
    private Date sheduleTime;
    @Column
    private String meetingHeading;
    @Column 
    private String comment;
    @Column
    private String roomName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meetingTypeID") 
    private MeetingTypes meetingTypes;






    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "releaseID") 
    private Releases releases;


    public Releases getReleases() {
        return releases;
    }

    public void setReleases(Releases releases) {
        this.releases = releases;
    }






    public MeetingTypes getMeetingTypes() {
        return meetingTypes;
    }

    public void setMeetingTypes(MeetingTypes meetingTypes) {
        this.meetingTypes = meetingTypes;
    }

    public Meetings() {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Meetings(int meetingID, Date sheduleTime, String meetingHeading,
            String comment, String roomName) {
        super();
        this.meetingID = meetingID;
        this.sheduleTime = sheduleTime;
        this.meetingHeading = meetingHeading;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.roomName = roomName;

    }

    public int getMeetingID() {
        return meetingID;
    }

    public void setMeetingID(int meetingID) {
        this.meetingID = meetingID;
    }

    public Date getSheduleTime() {
        return sheduleTime;
    }

    public void setSheduleTime(Date sheduleTime) {
        this.sheduleTime = sheduleTime;
    }

    public String getMeetingHeading() {
        return meetingHeading;
    }

    public void setMeetingHeading(String meetingHeading) {
        this.meetingHeading = meetingHeading;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getRoomName() {
        return roomName;
    }

    public void setRoomName(String roomName) {
        this.roomName = roomName;
    }




}
```

---

```
package pearson.dashboard.model;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

@Entity
public class Releases {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int releaseID;  
    @Column
    private String orcleCode;
    @Column
    private String status;
    @Column
    private Date staging;
    @Column
    private Date cabCall;
    @Column 
    private Date rrr;
    @Column
    private String remarks;
    @Column
    private String releaseName;
    @Column 
    private Date prodDate;  

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teamID")
    private Teams teams;

    public Teams getTeams() {
        return teams;
    }
    public void setTeams(Teams teams) {
        this.teams = teams;
    }










    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "releases",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Meetings> meetings;        

    public List<Meetings> getMeetings() {
        return meetings;
    }
    public void setMeetings(List<Meetings> meetings) {
        this.meetings = meetings;
    }
















    public Releases() {}
    public Releases(int releasID, String orcleCode, String status,
            Date staging, Date cabCall, Date rrr, String remarks,
            String releaseName,Date prodDate) {
        super();
        this.releaseID = releasID;
        this.orcleCode = orcleCode;
        this.status = status;
        this.staging = staging;
        this.cabCall = cabCall;
        this.rrr = rrr;
        this.remarks = remarks;
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
        this.prodDate = prodDate;
    }

    public int getReleaseID() {
        return releaseID;
    }
    public void setReleaseID(int releaseID) {
        this.releaseID = releaseID;
    }

    public String getOrcleCode() {
        return orcleCode;
    }
    public void setOrcleCode(String orcleCode) {
        this.orcleCode = orcleCode;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Date getStaging() {
        return staging;
    }
    public void setStaging(Date staging) {
        this.staging = staging;
    }
    public Date getCabCall() {
        return cabCall;
    }
    public void setCabCall(Date cabCall) {
        this.cabCall = cabCall;
    }
    public Date getRrr() {
        return rrr;
    }
    public void setRrr(Date rrr) {
        this.rrr = rrr;
    }
    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }
    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }
    public String getReleaseName() {
        return releaseName;
    }
    public void setReleaseName(String releaseName) {
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
    }
    public Date getProdDate() {
            return prodDate;
        }
    public void setProdDate(Date prodDate) {
            this.prodDate = prodDate;
        }           

}
```

part of Controller************

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import pearson.dashboard.dto.NewMeeting;
import pearson.dashboard.service.MeetingService;
import pearson.dashboard.service.MeetingTypeService;
import pearson.dashboard.service.MemberService;
import pearson.dashboard.service.SwarmingScheduleService;

@Controller
public class MeetingTypesController {
@Autowired
private MeetingTypeService  meetingTypeService;
//@Autowired
//private MeetingService meetingService;
@Autowired
private SwarmingScheduleService swarmingScheduleService;
@Autowired
private MemberService memberService;

@RequestMapping(value="/detailsPage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getAllmeeting(@ModelAttribute NewMeeting newMeeting,BindingResult result,Map<String, Object> map){
    int releaseID = newMeeting.getReleaseID();


    map.put("meetingList", meetingTypeService.getAllMeetingTypes(releaseID));   
    map.put("swarmingScheduleList",swarmingScheduleService.gettAllSwarming() );
    map.put("memberList",memberService.gettAllMembers() );
    return "details";







}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HQL not sql so in hql no keyword like join alternatively you can implement join using `objecta.objectb` and so on so you have to create your query like below

`Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM MeetingTypes  mt WHERE mt.meetings.releases.id = :releaseID");`

for more details see the below link

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms

Comment: I tried but it is not working..i am doubt whether createSQLQuery or createQuery ,we shude use there..i post my release Entity also now..I dont know how to solve this ..thanks your help..if u can help ..i apriciate lot

Comment: @user2991030  user createQuery for hql queries

Comment: ah Thanks quik reply..butit is not working--- Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from MeetingTypes where releases.releaseID = :releaseID ");
  query.setParameter("releaseID", releaseID);
  List list = query.list();

  return list;--i tried this also ..it give Error---HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [Releases.releaseID], unexpected token [Releases] [from pearson.dashboard.model.MeetingTypes where Releases.releaseID = :releaseID ]

Comment: `Unable to resolve path [Releases.releaseID]` one min checking your whole code

Comment: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingTypes",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    private List<Meetings> meetings;
    public List<Meetings> getMeetings() {
        return meetings;
    }`
are you expecting this or this `Private Meeting meeting` in your MeetingTypes

Comment: when i call MeetingTypes,I expecting data from MeetingType +meeting+ Releases because i think i have mapped those then i can get..Thanks for trying to helm me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42628/discussion-between-deepak-and-user2991030)

Answer (score 0):

Your HQL query should be like this

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM MeetingTypes AS mt WHERE mt.meetings.releases.id = :releaseID");
query.setParameter("releaseID", releaseID);
return query.list();
```

hope this will solve your problem.
hopefully your Releases Entity something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="meetings")
public class Meetings {
    @Id
    @Column(name="meetings_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

   //setter & getters   
}
```

also you have not mentioned your `name` parameter in `@Table()` annotation is your table name is same as class name ?

**@Entity**

The @Entity annotation is used to mark this class as an Entity bean. So the class should atleast have a package scope no-argument constructor.

**@Column**

The @Column annotation is used to specify the details of the column to which a field or property will be mapped. ***If the @Column annotation is not specified by default the property name will be used as the column name.***

**@Table**

The @Table annotation is used to specify the table to persist the data. The name attribute refers to the table name. ***If @Table annotation is not specified then Hibernate will by default use the class name as the table name***.

**createQuery() VS createSQLQuery()**

1. ***createQuery()***

   Create a new instance of Query for the given ***HQL query*** string.
2. ***createSQLQuery()***

   Create a new instance of SQLQuery for the given ***SQL query*** string.

Comment: I tried but it is not working..i am doubt whether createSQLQuery or createQuery ,we shude use there..i post my release Entity also now..I dont know how to solve this ..thanks your help..if u can help ..i apriciate lot

Comment: where is @Table(name="table_name") where you configure the table name with entity and if you are using logging the set the Hibernate SQL log level to DEBUG using log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG and check out query in log statement.

Comment: also you are writing HQL query in createSQLQuery() method.